# Closing a Ratchet IOServer

Tags: php, ratchet

Is there a method of terminating `IOServer`'s `loop`?

I'm using WebSockets as a hacky inter-app communication system (believe me, if I could use anything else, I would), but I can't break out of the loop and continue my application after calling `run()` on `IOServer`.

Do I need to subclass `IOServer` into `TerminatableIOServer` or does this feature already exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call `stop()` on the `IOServer`'s loop.

**Launcher.php**

```
namespace MyApp;

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use MyApp\Server;

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new Server('stopCallback')
        )
    ),
    $this->port()
);

$server->run();

echo "if the server ever determines it should close, this will be printed.";


// when loop completed, run this function
function stopCallback() {
    $server->loop->stop();
}
```

**Server.php**

```
namespace MyApp;

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Server implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $callback;

    public function __construct($callback) {
        $this->callback = $callback;
    }

    // custom function called elsewhere in this class whenever you want to close the server.
    protected function close() {
        call_user_func($this->callback);
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do this if the loop were to be terminated prematurely. For example, if the script crashed or closed for some random reason, how do you close off this port so it can be used again?

Comment: @DanHastings Killing the PHP process that has the lock on the port should work

Comment: Awesome, you made my day :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function stopCallback() {
  global $server;
  $server->loop->stop();
}
```

If you don't do that it will give error.

Comment: I can't see any difference to the 7 years old [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21651167/3749896).